# Certificate issue when Connecting with Azure Service Management API

Tags: .net, api, azure, certificate, x509certificate

I am getting an issue while fetching the list of hosted services. My code is as below:

```
 string requestUrl = "https://management.core.windows.net/" + SubscriptionID + "/services/hostedservices";

        string ReturnBody = string.Empty;
        WebResponse resp = null;
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            NameValueCollection RequestHeaders = new NameValueCollection();
            RequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", x_ms_version);
            X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(CertificatePath);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
            if (RequestHeaders != null)
                request.Headers.Add(RequestHeaders);
            resp = request.GetResponse();              
        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            //ERROR: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.” error.
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (resp != null) { resp.Close(); }
            resp = null;
        }
```

I am getting "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" while running above code...
One starnge point regarding this is that same code is working fine in one of my WPF application, but giving an error in Web Application.
So, it may issue of IIS security, I have made unsuccessfull attempt by giving permission to everyone for that folder.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

**Naresh Goradara**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I responded to this question on MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/5e6a2cfd-c2b6-4880-a79c-4bf39f4d7ca8/#b427afb6-d68f-4591-8466-870e791b43c9

Did you try out the suggestion I made? What's the error you're getting even after that.

Gaurav

Comment: Hi, Gaurav, I have set full access to my VD, but still not working.

Comment: Naresh --> Actually you would need to provide full access to your certificate. So what you would do is find the certificate file, right click and then under security tab provide Everyone with full permissions. That should do the trick.

Comment: @Gaurav; still I am getting an error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
What can be the issue?

Comment: This is totally weird. I just copied your code and built a small ASP.Net project and when I ran it from Visual Studio (both as Administrator and Non-Administrator), it worked perfectly fine. I can see the list of my hosted services. Can you check if you've uploaded .cer file you're using in "CertificatePath" in Windows Azure Portal under "Management Certificates" section?

Comment: As I told you, same is working in website if I run it from default port, but problem starts when I run it under **IIS** by creating virtual dir.

Comment: I am also seeing the same thing as you are. Let me try something out and get back to you.